# Count Objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, count

I am working with PHP `arrays` and `objects`. I have been working with them for quite a while now. However, I am stuck at a problem, which might have a really simple solution.

I have a variable `$products` inside a function which receives value on call. I am trying to count the objects in the variable to see how many products are inside it. I tried the simple `count($products)` and `count((array)$products)` function and it isn't working. I know that isn't the best way to count the objects.

Is there any way to count them?

```
object(stdClass)#46 (3) {
  ["0"]=>
  object(stdClass)#47 (1) {
    ["productid"]=>
    string(2) "15"
  }
  ["1"]=>
  object(stdClass)#48 (1) {
    ["productid"]=>
    string(2) "16"
  }
  ["2"]=>
  object(stdClass)#48 (1) {
    ["productid"]=>
    string(2) "26"
  }
}
```

I need this to return `3`

```
object(stdClass)#20 (1) {
  ["productid"]=>
  string(2) "21"
}
```

I need this to return `1`

Comment: It would make your life a lot easier if you used arrays of objects instead of an object containing numeric properties. How are you generating this structure and can you change it?

Comment: Create a class for these product objects and have it implement the Countable interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, using objects for this seems a very bloated method. Using a simple array would be much easier and faster.

This:

```
object(stdClass)#46 (3) {
    ["0"]=>
        object(stdClass)#47 (1) {
            ["productid"]=>
              string(2) "15"
    }
}
```

Could just be this:

```
array(0 => 15);
```

Or even this:

```
array(15);
```

Your example only seems to be storing a product id, so you don't strictly need a key of "productid"

Is there any specific reason you need to use objects?

Answer (score 4):

The count function is meant to be used on

Arrays
Objects that are derived from classes that implement the countable interface
A stdClass is neither of these. The easier/quickest way to accomplish what you're after is

```
$count = count(get_object_vars($products));
```

This uses PHP's get_object_vars function, which will return the properties of an object as an array. You can then use this array with PHP's count function.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
$count = sizeof(get_obj_vars($products))

Here `get_obj_vars` function converts the `$products` variable into an array and the `sizeof` function counts the size of array and stores it into the variable `$count`

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar to

```
count(get_object_vars($obj));
```

But it seems a bit strange to use a stdClass as an array. Why do you do that?